# appending json files for mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

This is more of a question in seeing if MySQL has any support for appending a JSON object without adding any extensions.

Say I have a JSON object that is in a person table in my MySQL server that contains the following:

```
    {"John":"male",
    "Jane":"female"}
```

and in any language that can execute MySQL code through their api wanted to add the following

```
    {"Jack":"male",
    "Jill":"female"}
```

to have the JSON object end up like this:

```
    {"John":"male",
    "Jane":"female",
    "Jack":"male",
    "Jill":"female"}
```

Would this be possible without grabbing the object and appending it within the code rather than executing a MySQL command. If it is possible, how would it be done?

I am currently using 10.3.22 of MariaDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`JSON_MERGE_PATCH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-merge-patch) to combine JSON objects.

```
UPDATE person 
SET json_col = JSON_MERGE_PATCH(json_col, '{"Jack":"male", "Jill":"female"}')
WHERE ...
```

Comment: (That function and `JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE` are available as of 5.7.22 and 10.2.25.)